# Spring Rest return a JSON response with a certain http response code

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring. I have a REST api written in Spring, but I don't know how to return a **JSON** response with a custom http response code.

I return a JSON response as follows:

```
public String getUser(String id){

...
return jsonObj;
}
```

But it always displays 200 http ok status code.

**Here are my questions:**

How can I synchronize the response JSON and HTTP code?

How is it possible to return JSON response and custom HTTP code in void function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How I do it

Here is how I do JSON returns from a Spring Handler method.
My techniques are somewhat out-of-date,
but are still reasonable.

**Configure Jackson**
Add the following to the spring configuration xml file:

```
<bean name="jsonView"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
</bean>
```

With that,
Spring will convert return values to JSON and place them in the body of the response.

**Create a utility method to build the ResponseEntity**
Odds are good that you will have multiple handler methods.
Instead of boilerplate code,
create a method to do the standard work.
`ResponseEntity` is a Spring class.

```
protected ResponseEntity<ResponseJson> buildResponse(
    final ResponseJson jsonResponseBody,
    final HttpStatus httpStatus)
{
    final ResponseEntity<ResponseJson> returnValue;

    if ((jsonResponseBody != null) &&
        (httpStatus != null))
    {
        returnValue = new ResponseEntity<>(
            jsonResponseBody,
            httpStatus);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

**Annotate the handler method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webServiceUri", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

you can also use the `@PostMethod` annotation

```
@PostMethod("/webServiceUri")
```

**Return `ResponseEntity` from the handler method**
Call the utility method to build the `ResponseEntity`

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseJson> handlerMethod(
    ... params)
{
    ... stuff

    return buildResponse(json, httpStatus);
}
```

**Annotate the handler parameters**
Jackson will convert from json to the parameter type when you use the `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseJson> handlerMethod(
    final WebRequest webRequest,
    @RequestBody final InputJson inputJson)
{
    ... stuff
}
```

### A different story

You can use the `@JsonView` annotation.
Check out the [Spring Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) for details about this.
Browse to the ref page and search for @JsonView.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 5):

Use `@ResponseStatus` annotation:

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public String getUser(String id) {...}
```

**Alternative way:** If you want to decide programmatically what status to return you can use `ResponseEntity`. Change return type of a method to `ResponseEntity<String>` and you'll be offered with a DSL like this:

```
ResponseEntity
        .status(NOT_FOUND)
        .contentType(TEXT_PLAIN)
        .body("some body");
```

Comment: I have if conditions. for e.g if a user was not found, return 404 status code, else return 200